# $(A\cap B)/C=A/C\cap B/C$ for ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, A,B,C ideals of $R$ with $C\subset A,B$.

$(A\cap B)/C=A/C\cap B/C$ for ideals?

One direction($\subset$) is clear but I am not sure about the other direction($\supset$). Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The quotient of ideals is simply the quotient as additive groups. Does this equality hold for abelian groups $A$, $B$, and $C$ with $C \subset A, B$?

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful comment! https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_of_Quotient_Groups